# How do i auto-scale ec2 instances in ECS cluster when service not listening on any port but SQS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-ecs

ECS auto-scaling option for instances are provided only when process is listening on some port. In my case, my process is receiving messages from queue. I want to auto-scale based on number of messages in queue (or even the CPU load) but I am not given that option. I can only auto-scale number of tasks. How do i configure to get that option?

Comment: I would try to publish a custom cloudwatch metric with the SQS queue size then define auto-scale based on that metric. (but never done this myself)

Comment: My issue is that auto-scaling ecs instances work only with load balancer. Since my job is listening to SQS, there is no load balancer. As a result, I am not sure, how to scale instances..

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work without LB? I've only used the fargate option, the service configuration has settings for autoscaling, where the policy can configure a metric and an action. Nothing bounded to the LB

Comment: Basically, for auto-scale of instances, it asks for what port container listens on .. and that is usually for traffic from LB. My process has no traffic thats in-bound. Instead, it just listens to SQS queue.

Comment: I have figured out a way that people use. They create a lambda that gets triggered based on alarm in cloud watch and scale out/in cluster.